# If $M$ is the span of a finite orthonormal set in a Hilbert space then $M$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Suppose that  $\{e_1,e_2,\dotsc,e_n\}$ is a finite orthonormal set in a Hilbert space.  I want to prove that $M= \operatorname{span}(\{e_1,e_2,\dotsc,e_n\})$ is closed. So what I was thinking is if I can show that $M$ is finite then I have that it is a finite subspace of my Hilbert space therefore it is complete and therefore closed.

But I'm wondering if it's true that if my set is finite then the span of my set is finite. And if thats true how do I go about proving it?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}^n$ (or $\mathbb{R}^n$ depending on your field) is isometrically isomorphic to $M$.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{R}$ is the span of $\{1\}$, so your attempt won't work. But write that $i:M\to H$ given by $i(e_j)=e_j$ is an isometry, and so send the complete space $M$ (because finite dimensional) to the complete and so closed set $M\subset H$, and the end of your proof works well.

Comment: i just dont understand why it has to be finite dimensional to be complete and if M is the span how do you know it finite??

Comment: It has not to be finite dimensional to be complete, but it is sufficient. It is finite by your hypothesis: $m=\mathrm{span}(e_1,\dots,e_n)$.

Comment: yes i just dont understand how the span of a finite set is finite

Comment: i don't really understand your proof... you're saying that because M is a subset of H then it is closed?

Comment: It is not finite, it is finite dimensional (over the fields $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, the only finite vector space is $\{0\}$). No, I am saying that $M$ is a complete subset of $H$ and so closed, as you say at the end of your first paragraph.

Comment: but isnt it enough to say that since M is a subspace of H it is complete therefore it is closed?

Comment: No since there could be vector subspaces of $H$ which are not complete: here I show quickly that if $M$ is finite dimensional, it has to be complete (you can of course directly use this argument if you know it, but without it it wouldn't be correct).

Comment: ok so over all you're creating an isometry from M to H then since f(M) = M and f(M) is a subset of H this implies M is a subset of H and then since M is finite dimensional it is complete that means it is a complete subspace of H which is closed? What i don't get is how a finite dimensional subspace is complete.

Comment: Oh okay: this is a general fact, a finite dimensional normed vector space is always complete (and this comes from the fact that all norms are equivalent in finite dimension)!

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a normed linear space over $S$ where $S=\Bbb R$ or $S=\Bbb C$.

THEOREM.   If $Y$ is a closed linear sub-space of $X$ and  $v\in X\setminus Y$ then $Z=\{y+sv:y\in Y\land s\in S\}$ is closed.

Proof: Suppose a sequence $(y_n+s_nv)_n$ converges in norm to $z,$ with $y_n\in Y$ and $s_n\in S.$

Case (i). If $(s_n)_n$ is not a bounded sequence then it has a sub-sequence $(s_{n_j})_j$ with $|s_{n_j}| \to  \infty$ as $j\to \infty,$ and  with each $s_{n_j}\ne 0.$ Then $$0=\lim_{j\to \infty} \|(s_{n_j})^{-1}y_{n_j}+v-(s_{n_j})^{-1}z\|$$ $$\text { and }\quad 0=\lim_{j\to \infty}\| (s_{n_j})^{-1}z\|.$$ $$ \text {But these imply that }\quad \lim_{j\to \infty}\|(s_{n_j})^{-1}y_{n_j}+v\|$$  which in turn implies that $(-v)\in \overline Y=Y,$ and hence $v\in Y$ (because $Y$ is a vector space), contradicting $v\not\in Y.$ So this case is impossible.

Case (ii). If $(s_n)_n$ is a bounded sequence then it has a sub-sequence $(s_{n_i})_i$ converging to some $s\in S.$ Then as $i\to \infty$ we have $y_{n_i}+(s_{n_i}-s)v \to z-sv\;$  and we have $(s_{n_i}-s)v\to 0. \;$ So $y_{n_i} \to z-sv.\;$ So with $y=z-sv$ we have $y\in \overline Y=Y,$ and $$z=(z-sv)+sv=y+sz\in Z.$$

COROLLARY: If $Z$ is a finite dimensional vector sub-space of $X$ then $Z$ is closed.

Proof: If not, then take a counter-example $Z$ with the least possible dimension, $m$ . Clearly $m\ne 0.$ (Note: $\dim Z=0$ iff $Z=\{0\}.$) So let $Z$ be the linear span of $B=(\{y_j: 1\leq j\leq m\},$ with $m>0.$ By the minimality of $m,$ the linear span $Y$ of $B\setminus \{y_m\}$ is closed. (Note: In case $m=1,$ the linear span of $\emptyset$ is defined to be $\{0\}.$) And $y_m\in X\setminus Y.$ By the theorem, $Z=\{y+sy_m:y\in Y\land s\in S\}$ is closed,  contrary to $Z$ being a counter-example.